# Check (assert) for valid date fails

Tags: c, function, time

I have a bit of code for checking if the input date is correct. Just a check if there is not more than 12 months, if the days in a given month are correct and it should also account for leapyears (so, basically a normal date check). Only out of place thing is that the year should not be lower than 2000. If the date is not valid the function should return "INVALID_DATE" (defined in the header as -1), if it is valid it should return 1.

```
#define INVALID_DATE (-1)
int valid_date(int y,int m,int d){
  if(y<2000){
    return INVALID_DATE;
  }
  if(m>12){
    return INVALID_DATE;
  }

  if ( y%400 == 0){                 //chcek for leapyear
    if((m==2)&&(d>29)){return INVALID_DATE;}
  }
  else if ( y%4 == 0 ){
    if((m==2)&&(d>29)){return INVALID_DATE;}
  }

  switch(m) {             //chcek if number of days is correct in given month
    case 1: if(d>31){return INVALID_DATE;break;}
    case 2: if(d>28){return INVALID_DATE;break;}
    case 3: if(d>31){return INVALID_DATE;break;}
    case 4: if(d>30){return INVALID_DATE;break;}
    case 5: if(d>31){return INVALID_DATE;break;}
    case 6: if(d>30){return INVALID_DATE;break;}
    case 7: if(d>31){return INVALID_DATE;break;}
    case 8: if(d>31){return INVALID_DATE;break;}
    case 9: if(d>30){return INVALID_DATE;break;}
    case 10:  if(d>31){return INVALID_DATE;break;}
    case 11:  if(d>30){return INVALID_DATE;break;}
    case 12:  if(d>31){return INVALID_DATE;break;}
  }
  return 1;
}

int main( int argc, char * argv [] ){
  assert(valid_date ( 2018, 1, 20 ) == 1);
  assert(valid_date(2000,14,10)==INVALID_DATE);
  assert(valid_date(2000,11,31)==INVALID_DATE);
  assert(valid_date(2000,2,29)==INVALID_DATE);
  assert(valid_date(2004,2,29)==1);         //fails
  assert(valid_date(2100,2,29)==INVALID_DATE);
  assert(valid_date ( 2018, 1, 28) == 1);
  assert(valid_date ( 2018, 1, 29) == 1); //fails
  assert(valid_date ( 2018, 1, 30) == 1); //fails
  assert(valid_date ( 2018, 1, 31) == 1);  //fails
}
```

I have comments on the lines (asserts) where it fails. I can maybe understand that it fails on the leapyear check, I am not sure that I have it correctly written but why on earth it fails when there is a day that is higher than 28. Can somebody please tell me what I am doing wrong ?

Thank you.

PS. This is for a school homework. (If it matters)

---

Fixed the switch(m). Changed

```
case 1: if(d>31){return INVALID_DATE;break;}
```

to

```
case 1: if(d>31){return INVALID_DATE;}break;
```

and it works. Thank you.

Still need to figure out why my leap years are not working. I tried to rewrite it to

```
if(y % 400 == 0 || (y % 100 != 0 && y % 4 == 0)){
if(m==2&&d>29){return INVALID_DATE;}
}
```

but it did not help. Does somebody know why it is not working?

Comment: You're accepting negative values for month and day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`if(...){return INVALID_DATE;break;}` will only break when the `if` is true. Else it will fall through.

So your call

```
assert(valid_date ( 2018, 1, 29) == 1);
```

will perform:

```
    case 1: if(d>31){return INVALID_DATE;break;}  // if is false; fall through
    case 2: if(d>28){return INVALID_DATE;break;}  // if is true: return invalid date
```

What you want is:

```
    case 1: if(d>31) return INVALID_DATE; break;
    case 2: if(d>28) return INVALID_DATE; break;
```

so the `break` is performed when the check is false, meaning the data is OK, and then `return 1;` at the end of the function.

Comment: A little more prodding of *"What do you think is happening when..."* is always good in answers to homework questions. (the old give a man a fish, you feed him for a day, teach a man to fish and you feed him for a lifetime....)

Comment: The `break` after `return` is redundant in `return INVALID_DATE; break;`

Comment: @KeineLust It's necessary. If the `if` check fails the `switch` must break there.

Comment: @KeineLust I've seen it argued both ways (for the generic `switch`). Yes, redundant, but yes include it to affirmatively show there is no fall through. I've even seen it argued as necessary in the `default` case at the end... I think at that level it is more a *style* point.

Comment: Yeah, that fixed that. Thank you. Still got to figure out why my leap years are not working correctly. But thanks.

Comment: @Jano: The formula for checking lap years is: `if ((m == 2) && (((y % 4 == 0) && (y % 100 != 0)) || (y % 400 == 0)))`